# How can I reproduce all formatting in another version of the same PDF?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

Using Adobe Acrobat DC (15.016), my grandfather added links, new text, and highlighted existing text on a PDF of 600 pages (hereafter PDF1) that somehow was corrupted because strangely, even after Text Recognition, most of the text failed to be searched and located.

My grandfather then received a corrected version of this PDF (hereafter PDF2) where now all the text can be searched. He neglected to request PDF2 before formatting on PDF1; but  how can he transfer or reproduce all his formatting in PDF1 to PDF2 efficiently, without repeating everything manually?

**Update on 2016/6/5, in response to user 'Max Wyss' 's answer:** This answer did not appear to resolve my problem, because after step 6:
1. all the text (added with 'Add Text') vanished.
2. The highlights changed in position, and so ceased to match and highlight the texts anymore.

Comment: To 1: the Add Text tool creates actually text in the imaging level, and not annotations; that text will disappear. To 2: The assumption was that the text did not change. Annotations are indeed placed at fixed coordinates, and do not have any tight connection with the associated text.

Answer (score 0):

If your grandfather added only annotations (comments, links etc.), and otherwise, the documents are the same (page by page), then it is easy to pass the annotations to the corrected version.

Actually, it is the other way round:

1. Open the first version (PDF1).
2. Open the Manage Pages toolset.
3. Select the Replace Pages tool.
4. Select the corrected version (PDF2) as replacement document.
5. Set to replace all pages in PDF1 with the pages from PDF2.
6. Confirm and wait until Acrobat is done.
7. Save the resulting document under another name.
8. Check the annotations.

If (as stated already) the pages are the same in PDF1 and PDF2, you now have a document with the pages from PDF2 and the annotations of PDF1.

Comment: Would you please respond in your answer, which is easier to read than comments?

Comment: Please see the update to my post above.